# Replacing Windows DLL in Unity with what in iOS?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to deploy a Unity test app to iOS to understand what we will need to provide to developers wishing to use our device. The device is custom hardware and shows up in Windows as a HID device over USB or BLE.

In the Windows builds the Unity script calls functions exposed in a C# DLL written targeting the "Unity 3.5 .net Subset Base Class Libraries" as required. The functions in that DLL make native calls to Windows functions like [HidP_GetCaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539715(v=vs.85).aspx), [SleepEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686307(v=vs.85).aspx), [ReadFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468(v=vs.85).aspx), etc.

Clearly that C# DLL is very Windows specific.

The calls into the C# DLL are mainly subscribing to events. For example here's the Start method in my Unity script

```
void Start () {
    DeviceManager.Instance.DeviceConnected += DeviceConnected;
    DeviceManager.Instance.DeviceDisconnected += DeviceDisconnected;
    DeviceManager.Instance.Initialize(Communication.AllSupported);
}
```

Unity prepares an Xcode project for me when I build this for iOS. What should I be making to replace the DLL so that Unity developers who want to write for our device can target iOS? Where do I replace the DLL calls to target this whatever-it-is?

Comment: first and foremost you need a replacement for that DLL that targets macOS. If that device and DLL are supplied by a 3rd party vendor you'll have to ask them for a macOS support library. If your org created the device and DLL then the first step would be porting *that* to macOS. If you keep the interface the same you'll don't have to change anything in Unity then.

Comment: Thanks datenwolf. Do you mean MacOS or iOS? I wrote the Windows DLL and have some experience with Swift iOS development. So, I just need to write an iOS library exposing the same functions, classes, etc? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: DLL written in C++?

Comment: The current one's C#, I've edited the question to make that explicit.

Comment: @datenwolf None of these look like a DLL I could drop into the Unity http://imgur.com/rx3APls

Comment: @dumbledad: Sorry, I meant iOS, which is similar enough to macOS so that the general steps are about the same. Oh, and if they're written in C# then they're going to be DLLs on macOS/iOS, too and be loaded, JITed and executed through Mono. Essentially porting will boil down to rewrite the C# code to use the APIs of iOS/macOS instead of the Windows APIs.